# Deleting segments of a text cell value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have many lines that follow a similar suit to the below format in my Excel sheet:

`JFB001 D (2 Stem Flower Spray Orange Handcrafted Sugar Decorations) Web.jpg`

What do I have to do, in order to delete everything starting -1 position from the first `(`, and ending -1 position from `.jpg` so I can achieve the following:

`JFB001 D.jpg`

Comment: I think you want LEFT(), CONCAT(), and RIGHT()

Comment: It would be nice to know what you've already tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the below formulas will be helpful to you.
[image]

**Formulas used:**

```
=LEFT(D2,FIND("(",D2,1)-1)                 -- Cell D4 above

=MID(D2,FIND(")",D2,1)+1,LEN(D2))          -- Cell E4

=CONCATENATE(D4,E4)                        -- Cell F4
```

Comment: The image is good - however, when you have formulas embedded in images like this, it's always helpful to list the formulas in text below it as well, so that readers can easily copy and paste.

Comment: obviously can use it in one line like this =CONCATENATE(LEFT(D2,FIND("(",D2,1)-1),MID(D2,FIND(")",D2,1)+1,LEN(D2)))

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
=MID(B2,1,FIND("(",B2,1)-2)&".jpg"
```

where `B2` is the cell that contains the long name that you want to shorten.

I've just manually added the `".jpg"` part, you can make it more dynamic if you have other extensions besides .jpg.